# Converting string with month that is not integer to datetime

Tags: c#

I have strings in the format

> Mar 25 2013 6:30PM

and I want to convert them to datetime objects in the format

> 2013-03-25 18:30:00

how would I go about doing this?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use:

```
 var date = DateTime.Parse("Mar 25 2013 6:30PM");

 Console.WriteLine(date.ToString()); /*This will output the date in the required format */
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
DateTime dt
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles style = DateTimeStyles.None;
DateTime.TryParseExact("Mar 25 2013 6:30PM", "MMM d yyyy h:mtt", provider, style, out dt);
```

Comment: -1, pretty sure your format is wrong. At the very least the space before `tt`

Comment: @musefan i have rectify it. Now working .tested

Comment: Yep, I tested your update too. Works well